# Python Requests and Forbes 'Welcome' page redirect

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Is it possible for Requests to navigate its way through the Forbes welcome page? I'm trying to access this article

```
http://www.forbes.com/sites/andygreenberg/2012/10/15/how-i-accidentally-helped-compromise-the-secret-keys-of-high-security-handcuffs/
```

which for most  will end up with a splash screen welcome page before then redirecting to the actual article itself. I note in Chrome the URL of the article is then appended with a value once it resolves to the actual article, though this seems random every time.

```
http://www.forbes.com/sites/andygreenberg/2012/10/15/how-i-accidentally-helped-compromise-the-secret-keys-of-high-security-handcuffs/#216cc0922071
```

I have a sense this may involve cookies but so far my code has not grabbed any html apart from the html making up the welcome page.

```
url = 'http://www.forbes.com/sites/andygreenberg/2012/10/15/how-i-accidentally-helped-compromise-the-secret-keys-of-high-security-handcuffs/'
hdrs = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0'}
session = requests.session()
text = session.get(url, headers=hdrs, allow_redirects=True)
print ('headers', text.headers)
print ('cookies', requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(session.cookies))
print ('html',  text.text)
```

Output

```
headers {'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8', 'Backend': 'templates', 'Date': 'Tue, 30 Aug 2016 22:37:15 GMT', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Language': 'en-US', 'X-Cnection': 'close', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Content-Length': '1983', 'Server': '', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
cookies {'forbesbeta': 'A'}
html <!DOCTYPE html><html class="no-js" lang=""><head><title>Forbes Welcome</title><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=2"><meta name="description" content="Forbes Welcome page -- Forbes is a global media company, focusing on business, investing, technology, entrepreneurship, leadership, and lifestyle."><meta name="keywords" content="business news, market analysis, company profiles, personal finance, management, entrepreneurship, investments, financial advice, economy, technology news"><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://i.forbesimg.com/welcomead/styles/abd4e3d6.main.css"><script type="text/javascript">fbs_settings = {
                mobile: 'false',
                preview: 'false',
                test: 'false',
                classes: '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'
            };</script><script type="text/javascript">try {
                fbs_settings.data = {"channel":"channel_0","section":"section_0","location":"welcomead_default","panel":"welcome_ad","contentPositions":[{"position":1,"title":"Quote of the Day","description":"\"Success is a terrible thing and a wonderful thing... Just do what you love.”","following":false,"byline":"Gene Wilder","hideDescription":false,"sponsored":false,"twitterHandle":"","hashtag":""}],"panelId":"panel4","limit":0,"swimlane":false,"more":false,"enableAds":false,"removeBVPrepend":false,"brandvoiceHeader":false,"profileLink":false,"fullListLink":false,"pagination":false,"filters":false,"year":0};
            } catch (err) {
                fbs_settings.data = null;
            }</script><script type="text/javascript">try {
                fbs_settings.angular_preload = ["//i.forbesimg.com/forbes/scripts/c632bd7f.vendor.js","//i.forbesimg.com/forbes/scripts/99f3b378.scripts.js","//i.forbesimg.com/forbes/styles/860430fd.main.css"];
            } catch (err) {
                fbs_settings.angular_preload = null;
            }</script><script src="http://i.forbesimg.com/welcomead/scripts/vendor/69216742.modernizr.js"></script></head><body><div id="app" class="container clearfix default-template ad-300-by-250"><div id="navigation"></div><div id="content"><div id="adblock-hover" class="hidden"><span class="close-btn preloaded"><span class="close">CLOSE</span> <i class="icon icon-close"></i></span> <img> <a href="//www.forbes.com/adblock/instructions/" target="_blank">More Options</a></div>  <script>(function() {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            var inviEles = document.getElementsByClassName('invisible');
                            for (var ele in inviEles) {
                                if (!inviEles[0]) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                inviEles[0].className = inviEles[0].className.replace('invisible', '');
                            }
                            if (window.performance && performance.mark) {
                                performance.mark('content_visible');
                            }
                        });
                    })();</script><div class="content-container"><div class="content-inner"><h1 class="title">  <i class="invisible branding icon icon-forbes-logo"></i> <span class="top invisible">Quote of</span> <span class="bottom invisible">the Day</span></h1><div class="body">  <p class="body-content invisible">"Success is a terrible thing and a wonderful thing... Just do what you love.”</p>  <p class="body-byline invisible">Gene Wilder</p>  </div></div></div><div class="circle-wrapper"><div class="circle invisible"></div><img class="circle fallback hidden" src="http://i.forbesimg.com/welcomead/images/circle.png"></div>  </div><div id="ads"></div></div><!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <script src="http://i.forbesimg.com/welcomead/scripts/b9b8347c.legacy.js"></script>
        <![endif]--><script src="http://i.forbesimg.com/welcomead/scripts/1a364ca6.vendor.js"></script><script src="http://i.forbesimg.com/welcomead/scripts/8951c3c8.main.js"></script></body></html>
```

I imagine that as a browser can eventually resolve to the article, Requests should be able to as well, but as I can't work out what Forbes is doing, I can't work out how to design the Requests argument appropriately. Any ideas?

Comment: requests does not run Javascript so it won't be happening. You will need something like Selenium and even then it will involve a wait and a button click. Also I am pretty sure you are violation their ToS by scraping.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at Selenium. A wait isn't too much of an issue as I've built delays into the script anyway to avoid getting blocked. As long as the 'button click' can be automated and doesn't actually involve me sitting there and clicking the button!

Comment: Yep, it can all be automated quite easily but you will definitely need something capable of running JS.

Comment: Hi James, could you solve this? I am trying to get a Forbes article OG tags and I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Cesar I've added a solution. If you need more pointers let me know what you're specifically trying to do and I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never bothered at the time but have used Selenium in a different project since and had a user request to provide an answer so here's the basics for getting going with selenium to get past the Forbes splash page.

You'll need to install a driver for selenium, either firefox driver, chrome driver or PhantomJS which is headless. If you're on Mac, chromedriver can be easily installed via Homebrew, or by copying the single PhantomJS driver file to the path indicated in the `#comment`

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'http://www.forbes.com/sites/andygreenberg/2012/10/15/how-i-accidentally-helped-compromise-the-secret-keys-of-high-security-handcuffs/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome() # or webdriver.PhantomJS('usr/bin/phantomjs')

browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1] /div/div[1]').click() #  a very explicit xpath to the continue button

# now grab whatever you want from the resulting code using...

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('css selector info').get_attribute('innerHTML')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('xpath info').get_attribute('innerHTML') 
# 'innerHTML grabs whatever the tags you select are surrounding, but other attributes are also possible such as ('href') on an <a> tag.
```